# How to prove $\cos \frac{2\pi}{9} + \cos \frac{4\pi}{9} + \cos \frac{8\pi}{9}$=0

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried letting $z=cis \frac{2\pi}{9}$
and using trigonometric identities i got $\frac{1}{2z^4} [\frac{z^9-1}{z-1}]-\frac{1}{2z^3} - \frac{1}{2}$
and since i assumed that z then $z^9=cis (2\pi) =1$
but i ended up with $\cos \frac{2\pi}{n} + \cos \frac{4\pi}{n} + \cos \frac{8\pi}{n} = \frac{(-1+i\sqrt(3))}{4}$

Comment: did you trig identities give you $\frac{1}{2z^4}$ or $\frac{z^4}{2}$ ? It is unclear from what was written

Comment: its $\frac{1}{2z^4}$

Comment: alright... I submitted an edit where I clear up all the fractions, but I assumed $\frac{z^4}{2}$ as that is how it would be read without the parentheses. As you have added them and edited it yourself, either my edit will not go through (I'll just redo it) or it will go through and have that in the opposite order... if so go ahead and fix it.

Comment: One way  that can be done with complex or not is that the sum of the first two terms is $(1/2)\cos(3\pi/9)\cos(\pi/9)=\cos(\pi/9)$. Then it's over.

Comment: Sorry, typo above, the $1/2$ should be $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_9 = e^{2\pi i/9}$ be a primitive $9^{\rm th}$ root of unity.  The given sum on the LHS is $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\zeta_9 + \zeta_9^{-1} + \zeta_9^2 + \zeta_9^{-2} + \zeta_9^4 + \zeta_9^{-4}\right).$$    Now if we recall that the roots of $z^9 - 1 = 0$ are $$\{\zeta_9^k\}_{k=0}^8,$$ and the sum of the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ is equal to the negative of the coefficient of the degree $(n-1)^{\rm th}$ term, then it follows that $$\sum_{k=0}^8 \zeta_9^k = 0,$$ and since $\zeta_9^0 = 1$, we readily obtain $$\sum_{k=1}^8 \zeta_9^k = -1.$$  And since $$\zeta_9^{-1} = \zeta_9^8, \quad  \zeta_9^{-2} = \zeta_9^7, \quad \zeta_9^{-4} = \zeta_9^5,$$ we see that the given sum is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\left(-1 - \zeta_9^3 - \zeta_9^6\right) = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\zeta_9^3 + \zeta_9^{-3}}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} - \cos \frac{6\pi}{9} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos \frac{2\pi}{9} + \cos \frac{4\pi}{9} + \cos \frac{8\pi}{9}=0$

Let $\frac{2\pi}{9}=t$, then

$\cos t + \cos 2t + \cos 4t=\cos t+\cos ^2t-\sin ^2t+\cos^2(2t)-\sin ^2(2t)=$

$=\cos t+\cos ^2t-\sin ^2t+(\cos ^2t-\sin ^2t)^2-(2 \sin t \cos t)^2=0$

$=\cos t+\cos ^2t-\sin ^2t+\cos ^4t+\sin ^4t-2 \cos ^2t \sin ^2t -4 \cos ^2t \sin ^2t =$

Try this. It should help you.